# Are local backups of iCloud photos and camera roll redundant?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, photos

Does icloud photos strip any metadata or change the quality? The camera roll adds 30 gb to my backup and seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"iCloud is sync, not backup" that is an argument I've heard whenever things go wrong in iCloud syncing etc. Backup is always good. You'd value it when you'd need it.

> Does icloud photos strip any metadata or change the quality?

None that I've observed so far. All my photos sync across iPhone and Mac and I do edits etc., on both of them. Metadata is not lost.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Since I have another device (macbook) that i have set to download full quality images from icloud photos then that adds enough redundancy to let me turn off camera roll from icloud backups. I think that's a reasonable approach.

Comment: @clifton I just re-read my answer.  I messed up the crucial part in the first line.. Please re-check .

Comment: Essential difference, yup.

Comment: @Tetsujin that made later half (" You' value it when you'd need it.")redundant too. I hope not many people read it in 16 minutes.

Comment: People only understand the meaning of backup once they loose everything...